# How to handle NAT traversal in c++ peer to peer application ( please code examples not theory )

Tags: java, c++, p2p, nat-traversal

I need to develop simple game that will be using peer to peer connection using centralize index manager server.

I know there is a problem when a client is trying to connect to another client that is behind a router. I was reading about NAT traversal that explains using mainly theory, but what I would really like to see is code examples with either C++ or Java.

Can you help me to understand the meaning of NAT traversal via code? Maybe some kind of open source simple client game ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NAT traversal is not that simple to get right.
STUN might help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN

Comment: yeah i know , what does peap to pear software do ?

Answer (score 0):

lib jingle? http://nutss.gforge.cis.cornell.edu//stunt.php ( http://www.cis.nctu.edu.tw/~gis87577/xDreaming/XSTUNT/index.html )